# What kind of conjugation is 謝んなくった？

Tags: conjugations

I'm playing through Toradora right now, and there's a scene where Ryuuji apologizes to his mom because he can't remember anything. She responds with 「ううん、謝んなくったっていいんだよ。」

I understand she's saying don't apologize, but I've never seen an ending with なくった before. Is this some kind of colloquial contraction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse ～なくたって?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19593/how-to-parse-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6)

Comment: That question looks useful, but it doesn't address the nasal assimilation of /ran/ → \*/rn/ → /ɴn/ (in other words らな→んな), and we might also notice that there's a small っ before たって here, unlike in the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「謝{あやま}**ん**なく**ったって**いい**ん**だよ。」

Needless to say, this is colloquial speech which uses what I call the "two distinct hallmarks" of colloquial speech -- **「ん」 and the small 「っ」**.

Now, watch the hallmarks disappear instantly as I put the phrase into the "dictionary" form.

> 「謝らなくてもいいのですよ」

In Kanto (and even a larger area because of TV), 「ら」 often changes to 「ん」 in **negative verb forms** in colloquial speech.

謝**ら**ない to 謝**ん**ない、わか**ら**ない to わか**ん**ない、太{ふと}**ら**ない to 太**ん**ない, etc.

「たって/ったって」 is also a very common 'word' which should be in any free online dictionaries.  Not sure about bilingual dictionaries as I do not use them (because I do not trust them much).

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-561378#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

「～～たって/ったって」 means 「～～ても」 or 「～～たとしても」= ***"even if"***.  Thus, 「謝んなくったって」 is in the concessive conditional form.  The speaker is  offering a concession to the listener.

「ったって」 sounds slightly more emphatic than 「たって」.  That is the power of the small 「っ」 to begin with.  With double small 「っ」, 「ったって」 would naturally sound very colloquial -- even to the point of sounding slangy.